# Type hinting a basic python function with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mypy, typing

I have a simple mathematical function which I feel should be easy enough to type hint:

```py
from typing import Any
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def func1(x: Any) -> Any:
    return 2 * x - 3 * np.sin(x) + 5
```

I'm using `mypy` as my type checker, and I want to type hint the function to get the following:

```py
# These are ok so mypy should be fine with them
print(func1(1) + 1)
print(func1(np.array([1, 2, 3])) + np.array([4,5,6]) * 100)

# This cannot run so mypy should hate this:
print(func1(""))
```

After looking over the docs ([here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html?highlight=data%20type%20api)) and trying to understand how `numpy`s custom types interact with python's built-ins the best I've come up with is as follows:

```py
from typing import Any, overload
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

@overload
def func1(x: np.number[Any] | int | float) -> np.floating[Any]: ...
@overload
def func1(x: NDArray[np.floating[Any]]) -> NDArray[np.floating[Any]]: ...

def func1(x: Any) -> Any:
    return 2 * x - 3 * np.sin(x) + 5


# These are ok so mypy should be fine with them
print(func1(1) + 1)
print(func1(np.array([1, 2, 3])) + np.array([4, 5, 6]) * 100)

# This cannot run so mypy should hate this:
print(func1(""))
```

which works, but feels much clunkier than it should be given how common functions like these surely are. Can anyone offer a better solution and/or point to somewhere where I can look over examples type hinting with numpy (since the docs seem abit lacking).

I'm running python 3.11 with numpy 1.23.5 and mypy 0.991. My mypy config file is as follows:

```
[tool.mypy]
show_error_codes = true

warn_redundant_casts = true
warn_unused_configs = true
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
strict = true

plugins = ["numpy.typing.mypy_plugin"]
```

Comment: i wouldn't bother differentiating between the two cases, and just use a union type covering all numpy-like types. After all, `NDArray` doesn't account for the shape anyway so why special case `[]`?